# OCaml - Save values of recursive function in hashtable

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml, hashtable

I have this function:

```
let rec  som a b acc = 
if a > b then acc else 
som (a+1) b (acc+(comb b a));;
```

And what I am trying to do is to save acc value in a hashtable, so my first try was:

```
let rec  som a b acc = 
if a > b then acc else 
som (a+1) b (acc+(comb b a)) Hashtbl.add a acc;;
```

but it does not work... How can I save the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  skeleton, you can try to add you code into it to get what you want. Maybe it will be helpful.

```
module Key = struct 
   type t=int
   let compare: t->t->int = fun a b -> (* return -1 if a<b, 0 if a=b,and 1 if a>b *)
   let equal = (=)
end
module H=Hashtbl.Make(Key)
let som =
   let h = H.create () in
   let rec f a b acc =
     try H.find h acc 
     with Not_found ->
       let ans = (* your evaluation code *) in
       H.add h acc ans;
       ans
   in
   f
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take a look at the signature of `Hashtbl.add`

```
('a, 'b) Hashtbl.t -> 'a -> 'b -> unit = <fun>
```

The first argument of the function is an hash table, then you need to create one. To do it, write `let h_table = Hashtbl.create 123456;;`. And to put it in context your add instruction become `HashTbl.add h_table a acc`

Next, you can't call this function at the same level of the recursive call. Indeed the function `som` take three arguments and you will face the following error message, `It is applied to too many arguments ...`.

And as you want to trace the value of `acc` you need to put it before the recursive call. Doing this can lead you to face some difficulty, then I've added below a hint.

```
let _ = Printf.printf "a\n" in 
  let _ = Printf.printf "b\n" in 
    (1+2)
;;
a
b                                                                                       
- : int = 3
```